# Bug in Teams when confirming domain

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have used teams before, and I recently left the company I was working for. I joined a new company and the first thing I wanted to implement here at this new company was to use SO Teams.

I didn't take screenshots, but wanted to let you know in the teams section when you first sign up you can specify an email address to verify the domain for your team. I left that page open that stated something about no domains have been registered.

When I got the email I clicked on it and this page came up even after I verified and had a green message thanking me that I verified my account, but still underneath it was this gray section that said I still had 0 domains or something to that effect.

I ended up having to refresh this same page again and it went away and stated my domain that I had registered. So it looks like some sort of bug where this div or message is not loaded correctly upon verifying the email. If it helps the email was for "Verify your email to add an email domain to MHSI" and my team name is MHSI. The buggy message is the one that now states:

"Anyone with an email address on one of these domains can join this team: mhsiglobal.com" But when I verified the email the verification took, and I got a green message claiming it verified, but this message about "Anyone with an email..." actually said something to the effect of "0 or no domains have been registered". It only refreshed after I refreshed the page a second time.

It was in Google Chrome, but it probably happens in Internet Explorer as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your report. This issue has now been fixed.

When users verify an email domain, we first update all the things that need to be updated and redirect them to the admin Manage Invites page. That page fetches all the email domains data from our *secondary* database, which is usually okay since the primary-secondary sync happens almost instantaneously. However, by the time the admin page loaded in your case, the database was still not in sync for some reason (which is rare, but it happens) and you got stale data. Refreshing the page a few seconds afterwards did the trick, as it gave the DBs a bit more time.

I changed the logic in the admin pages so it should always read from the primary DB, so we shouldn't see similar races in the future. Fix will be up with our next prod build.

Comment: Proof that all systems including that of stackoverflow arent always that great!  Thank you